# TBXML parsing value of attribute named

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, parsing, tbxml

I have this xml:

```
            <AccountsList>
               <Account 
            Cod="0000" 
            AccountNumber="12345" 
            AccountName="John" 
            AccountSecondName="Wilson" />

        </AccountsList>
```

For parsing it I use

```
            [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"Cod" forElement:element]
            [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"AccountNumber" forElement:element]
            [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"AccountName" forElement:element]
            [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"AccountSecondName" forElement:element]
```

But if xml came without COD:

```
            <AccountsList>
               <Account 

            AccountNumber="12345" 
            AccountName="John" 
            AccountSecondName="Wilson" 
                        />
        </AccountsList>
```

I have crash! How I can check exist

```
            [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"Cod" forElement:element]
```

or not?

if struct don't help :(

```
             if ([TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"Cod" forElement:element])
```

It's always return TRUE

**Solution:**

Now I try to check for empty string and this help me.

```
          if ([TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"Cod" forElement:element] isEqualToString:@"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for retrieving the attribute values:

```
TBXMLAttribute * attribute = element->firstAttribute;

//Checking attribute is valid or not
while (attribute)
{
    //Here you can check the `Cod` attribute exist or not
    NSLog(@"%@->%@ = %@",[TBXML elementName:element],[TBXML attributeName:attribute], TBXML attributeValue:attribute]);

    // Next attribute
    attribute = attribute->next;
}
```

Comment: Attribute <Account......../> will be always valid because AccountNumber, AccountName, AccountSecondName remain there!

Comment: @Rubik: yeah sure, but you can put an if condition for checking if the Cod attribute exist or not. If exist do the corresponding actions.